# How do I remove items from generic list, based on multiple conditions and using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have two lists, one containing urls and another, containing all MIME file extensions. I want to remove from the first list all urls that point to such files.

Sample code:

```
List<string> urls = new List<string>();
urls.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");
urls.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/dir/some.pdf");
urls.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/dir/some.doc");

//total items in the second list are 190
List<string> mime = new List<string>();
mime.Add(".pdf"); 
mime.Add(".doc"); 
mime.Add(".dms"); 
mime.Add(".dll");
```

One way to remove multiple items is:

```
List<string> result = urls.Where(x => (!x.EndsWith(".pdf")) && (!x.EndsWith(".doc")) && (!x.EndsWith(".dll"))).ToList();
```

However, there are more than 190 extensions in my second list.

The question - can I remove the items from the first list with a one liner or is using a foreach loop the only way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to create a new list with only the items matching your condition:

```
List<string> result = urls.Where(x => !mime.Any(y => x.EndsWith(y))).ToList();
```

If you want to actually remove items from source, you should use `RemoveAll`:

```
urls.RemoveAll(x => mime.Any(y => x.EndsWith(y)));
```

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Author uses the same approach already, where he creates a new list instead of removing items from the source. But yeah, updated my answer with actual removal code.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, I was just adding clarification for passers-by :-)

Comment: `Any` short circuits exactly the same way `All` does. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1173

Comment: Perhaps, I hadn't quite worked through the logic in my Friday morning brain. I'd need to stick it through ReSharper to confirm lol, nice link btw, that has changed since I last looked at it.

Answer (score 8):

here is a one liner that fits your needs

```
urls.RemoveAll(x => mime.Any(y => x.EndsWith(y)));
```

maybe this is a safer appraoach

```
urls.RemoveAll(x => mime.Contains(Path.GetExtension(x)));
```

When you have URLs like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/dir/some.ashx?ID=.pdf` you should think about another approach